# Manhwa where the (female) main character reincarnates into a novel as the villain. Her friend reincarnates as the protagonist

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read a manhwa where the female lead had a "friend" who used to harass her and ruined his reputation. The female lead was on the balcony of her school with her friend and I don't know if she pushed her or jumped but they both committed suicide and were reincarnated in a novel.

I think the friend was the protagonist and she the villain

Comment: "*ruined his reputation*" - Who is 'he' in this sentence?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: These [tropes](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/all?include_tags=1262,1261) are very common indeed. Is there anything else you can give us? For example, what were the character's names? What did they look like? Was this aimed at adults (with sex/nudity/gore) or younger audiences? How did they reincarnate? Did they escape at the end? How was she villainous (e.g. what did she do that was bad?). Was there magic and wizardry? What was the setting of the novel?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is *[The Villainess Becomes the Leading Lady](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-villainess-becomes-the-leading-lady)*.

> Reborn into a fantasy novel as a wicked character fated to meet an early demise, Minjoo - now Dahlia Margaret - has a lot on her plate right from the start. But at least she’s now free of **her vicious high school bully**, Sooyeon. Or is she? When Dahlia meets Flore, her estranged sister and the protagonist of the novel, she is shocked to find that **the girl bears a suspicious resemblance to the classmate who tormented her**. Now, driven by the desire to save her own life and also get revenge, Dahlia needs to make a powerful ally, and she has her eye on a handsome royal who just might be perfect for the job. However, a deal with this mysterious man might mean more than she bargained for...

The balcony scene is in the second chapter. The first chapter is after the reincarnation; this is a flashback. The protagonist is on the school rooftop and gives her bully a note stating "this is all your fault". She jumps off the roof and the "friend" goes with her, I believe to ensure that either both die or neither dies. Both girls reincarnate in the world of a novel; the protagonist becomes the villainess character, while the bully becomes the heroine of the novel.

[image]